# pd.read_excel() ignores filters

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm working with some xlsx files and need to import them into program. I've written a script that handles everything I need it to do.

However, I need to apply filters to the table in excel before importing them in.

When I apply filters and prep the table to import into python, python reads the entire table ignoring all the filters.

My work around has been filtering what I need then copying that to a new sheet. Then when reading into excel I specify the new sheet of filtered data that I'm looking for.

Is there a way to read the filtered table into excel directly?

Or Should I just import the entire table and apply those same filters using pandas in my script instead?

Comment: AFAIK not doable with pandas, use openpyxl or maybe xlsxwriter directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can't read only visible rows *and/or* columns of an Excel spreadsheet with [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas).

To do that, you need some help from [openpyxl](/questions/tagged/openpyxl) (`!pip install openpyxl`) :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

wb = load_workbook("file.xlsx")
ws = wb.active # or wb["SheetName"] # <- change the name here

rows = [[c.value for c in r] for r in ws.iter_rows()
         if not ws.row_dimensions[r[0].row].hidden]

df = pd.DataFrame(data= rows[1:], columns=rows[0])
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   col  col2
0  foo   1.0
2  baz   3.0
```

Input used (*spreadsheet*) :

[image]

Comment: This is great Thanks!

I ended up just using pandas to filter so eliminate the extra step of doing it in excel and copying to a new sheet.

Comment: Yes, it you really have the choice, go for it and read the entire spreadsheet with `read_csv` and then filter your rows and/or columns. Otherwise, you now you know how to appoarch it with openpyxl ;)